# Spring Cloud DataFlow and Kafka Security

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to configure authentication for Spring Cloud DataFlow for Apache Kafka?
Where can I see examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current GA release of Kafka binder in Spring Cloud Stream/Spring Cloud Data Flow is based on Kafka 0.8.2. The 0.9 release of Kafka includes security support and we have [recently merged](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/2) the 0.9 compatibility. We are yet to review the security capabilities, though. It'd be great if you can share your use-cases, so we can validate as part of our acceptance.

You can track the release progress [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/milestone/1).